# Create a folder using substring of filename

Tags: batch-file, directory

I want to fetch two sub string from my file name in order to create Folder String.
My file name is "SM-SM-ABC_ab12 cd34_AA 11_abc123.txt"
here "ab12 cd34" is 1st folder and "AA 11" is 2nd folder
I have written a code but After adding @Compo code I ma not able to move file to directory.  I want to move multiple files to respective folders.
Can some one help whats wrong?

```
@Echo Off

set Path1= d:\A
:: SDate=DAYMONTHYEAR FORMAT of Systemdate
echo %Path1%
set SDate=%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%%date:~10,4%
echo %SDate%

::Variable for folder path

Pushd %Path1%
for %%i in (*.*) do SET "FPath=%%~ni"
For /F "Tokens=2-3 Delims=_" %%A In ("%FPath%") Do (
    Set "FoldOne=%%A"
    Set "FoldTwo=%%B"
if not exist "%Path1%\%FoldOne%\%FoldOne%\%SDate%" (
   mkdir "%Path1%\%FoldOne%\%FoldOne%\%SDate%" )
   move %Path1%\* "%Path1%\%FoldOne%\%FoldTwo%\%SDate%\"
echo test %Path1%
echo test %FPath%
)

GoTo :EOF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```bat
@Echo Off

Set "FPath=SM-SM-ABC_ab12cd34_AA11_abc123.txt"

For /F "Tokens=2-3 Delims=_" %%A In ("%FPath%") Do (
    Set "FoldOne=%%A"
    Set "FoldTwo=%%B")

Echo(%%FoldOne%%=%FoldOne%
Echo(%%FoldTwo%%=%FoldTwo%

Timeout -1
GoTo :EOF
```

**[Edit /]**
The following code may provide you with a solution for your updated requirements:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "Path1=D:\A"
If /I Not "%CD%"=="%Path1%" Pushd "%Path1%" 2>Nul || Exit/B
For /F "EOL=L" %%A In ('WMIC OS GET LocalDateTime') Do For %%B In (%%~nA
) Do Set "SDate=%%B"
Set "SDate=%SDate:~6,2%%SDate:~4,2%%SDate:~,4%"
For %%A In ("*_*_*_*.*") Do Call :Sub "%%A"
Timeout -1
GoTo :EOF

:Sub
For /F "Tokens=2-3 Delims=_" %%A In (%1) Do If Not "%%A"=="" If Not "%%B"=="" (
    If Not Exist "%%A\%%B\%SDate%\" MD "%%A\%%B\%SDate%"
    Move %1 "%%A\%%B\%SDate%")
```

Comment: Bingo...!
But I have some doubt. Can you please explain.. How you have passed  Folder two name in B.
Also it is working for single file what if I have multiple files with same format.

Comment: I split the file name into four tokens each delimited by an underscore. Token 1=SM-SM-ABC, Token 2=ab12cd34, Token 3=AA11, Token 4=abc123.txt. I asked for tokens 2 and 3 which are effectively %%A and %%B.

Comment: Hey @Compo Thanks.  I have made changes in my question. and used your script. Can you please check and help again?

Comment: I have provided an appended, but untested, solution in response to your updated requirements.

Comment: Hi @Compo thanks for your reply.   I am almost dont with script. but stuck with some silli mistake. can you please check this link once    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43114274/function-returning-variable-in-batch-file